# How to compute a correlation from Euclidean Distance?

Tags: python, math, distance, linear-algebra, correlation

Is it possible **to compute a correlation between two vectors using Euclidean Distance** ?

What I mean by **Euclidean distance** is :

```
Euclidean(X,Y) = sqrt((x1 - y1)*(x1 - y1) + ... + (xN - yN)*(xN - yN))
```

Is it possible if we standardize or normalize the vectors or even without normalization ?

What I'm looking for is to **compute a score between 0 and 1**. (1 ~ high correlation)

For now, I get a distances's vector. I divide it by the max distance.
I obtain the vector D.

And then : **1 - D**.

Do you think it's **a good way to obtain a score from Euclidean distance** ?

I'm also interested to have **in one place all different correlation measures** and their application field.

Comment: Dot product of two normalized vectors ranges from (0,1).  That would work.

Comment: Thanks but I really want it to use the Euclidean Distance / or something "very" similar.

Comment: You obviously don't understand vectors.  How do you normalize a vector?  Using the Euclidian distance.  The dot product includes both.

Comment: Dot product is the same as Euclidien distance : see the polarization identity  (second formula in this entry : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity)

Comment: I understand vectors... I already did normalization on the vectors. What guarantees the dot product to be lower than 1 ?
The Euclidian Distance is : (x1 - y1)^2 + ... + (xN - yN)^2

Comment: I think you're going to have to be more clear on exactly what you mean when you use the term "correlation".  What's wrong with the Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient definition (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient)?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  If (0, 1) was the requirement it could be mapped to that range, but it's a mistake on my part.  I've amended the answer below.

Comment: I would like to have more than one measure for correlation. I already have the Pearson one. Is it possible to obtain something similar using the Euclidean Distance ? I did it somehow but I would like to know if maybe there's something "recommended". Thanks ;)

Comment: I want to have measures that give me  results I can compare. For example if my average correlation for Pearson is 0.70. I'm not sure about my measure from Euclidian Distance if I have the average is 0.97. (Too close from 1 I think)

Comment: @andand I've been more clear ?

Comment: @DavidK possibly... I've put together a possible approach which I posted below.

Comment: Please don't give negative points to my question. The first answer is not was I was looking for. But my question is clear. Dot product is not what I was looking for. My question is clear : I did that. Does it make sense ? What do you think ? Could it be better ? If you don't know or don't understand, don't give negative points ! Let others answer ! And Thanks to everyone ;)

Comment: And don't close my question please because I won't see the point of asking it if it's closed and if I stay without answers. Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are any of a number of ways you can determine how similar two vectors are, though I suspect not all of them are strictly speaking correlation measures.  If you're interested in using the magnitude of the vectors and their difference, the obvious metric would be the relative magnitude of the difference vector and the average magnitude of the two given vectors.  For instance given vectors `X` and `Y`, which are not both 0, you could calculate a metric `M`:

```
       2∙||X-Y||
M  = -------------
     ||X|| + ||Y||
```

Now this will be somewhat reverse of what you're looking for, where values close to 0 represent vectors that are relatively close to each other and there's not really a bound on how large this can get.  However, there are ways to get an `M'` based on `M`.  One way of doing that might be:

```
M' = 1-2∙atan(M)/π
```

Another way to get an `M'` based on your description is to use exponential decay as in:

```
M' = exp(-M)
```

In either case `M'` will be 1 when the vectors are identical and will asymptotically approach 0 the greater their difference relative their average lengths.

I'm not aware of any formal name given to this approach (that doesn't mean there isn't one).  I just kind of made it up based on what I perceived to be your requirements.  However, I'm still not clear on exactly what you're looking for, so if this isn't what you need, then describe why this won't work for you so I or others can better understand your requirements and offer a better solution.

Comment: Thank you very much; this is the kind of answer I was looking for.
I know that Euclidean Distance can be used to calculate correlations between genes. My question was : How to transform the distance into a score that would be similar to the Pearson  correlation.
I don't understand why some people want to close my question ...

Answer (score 0):

Given two vectors in 3D space `u = (u1, u2, u3)` and `v = (v1, v2, v3)` you can calculate unit vectors for each one by dividing each component by the magnitude, which is the Euclidian length of the vector:

```
m = u/mag(u) = (u1, u2, u3)/sqrt(u1*u1 + u2*u2 + u3*u3) = (m1, m2, m3)
n = v/mag(v) = (v1, v2, v3)/sqrt(v1*v1 + v2*v2 + v3*v3) = (n1, n2, n3)
```

The dot product of the two unit vectors varies from (-1, 1):

```
m dot n = m1*n1 + m2*n2 + m3*n3
```

Comment: Sorry but it's not what I was looking for. I know dot product.